# How to compile PECL mailparse for Windows x64

Tags: php, windows, 64-bit, pecl

My Cerberus installation fails when testing the php_mailparse lib.  After some research, I understand that PECL does not supply an x64 version of their dll for windows.

Can anyone provide instructions on how I might go about compiling the following lib for x64?  Is VS my best option and if so, a quick overview would be very helpful.
[link text](http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse)

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: This is probably a good starting point... http://www.cerb4.com/forums/showthread.php?t=40

Comment: What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: Thanks Frank, but that's all non-windows specific. I need to be able to compile the windows dll version of the lib.

Here's the error message:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Program Files\\PHP\\ext\\php_mailparse.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Comment: And where did you get that .dll from? Or how was it compiled? Was it the result of `pecl install mailparse`? (Haven't tried with windows yset that but there's definitely code for compilation in pear/pecl for windows)

Answer (score 1):

just grab the geoip.c and compile it on windows with this tool: http://sourceforge.net/downloads/mingw/